# How to fix "Unknown class RootViewController in Interface Builder file" ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I've read a number of similar posts but I cannot get an answer that works for me. I have this beginning in my AppDelegate:

```
//LOAD WINDOWS

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        self.initialViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.window setRootViewController:self.initialViewController];
    } else {
        self.patternViewController = [[PatternViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatternView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [self.window setRootViewController: self.patternViewController];

    }

    return YES;
```

This is working for the iPad version, but not for the iPhone. I get these messages in the console:

1. Unknown class RootViewController in Interface Builder file.
2. Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

The PatternView_iPhone xib is of the PatternViewController class.

In the project summary, I have these settings:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: What class is the File's Owner of the PatternView_iPhone.xib? Do you have a class named RootViewController anywhere in your project?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The class for the xib is PatternViewController. I have run searches and cannot find any reference to RootViewController. However, if it's in one of my xibs somewhere, I guess I'll have to go through them with an XML editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says that there is object whose class name is **RootviewController** in the xib .Open the xib/storyboard as source (Right click and open as source code) and search RootviewController. Find where the tag comes and find the object and change it to valid object.

Comment: I didn't want to do that, as I'm lazy, but I found an obscure reference, so many thanks for pushing me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is an old post, but this is my exact error message for a Swiftify'd project.

In XCode 14.2, I searched the project for files containing 'RootViewController' and found MainWindow.xib.  This indeed was the source of the message, as changing the name in the source code as suggested by @Lithu above changed the error message.

With help from ChatGPT 4, I followed the `RootViewController` link from the search result into the Interface Builder view of the MainWindow.xib.  There I changed the Class name from 'RootViewController' to something else (drop down list), then changed it back and rebuilt.

Error gone, the source view of the file showed that customModule and customModuleProvider tags had been added to the relevant line:

```
<viewController id="8" customClass="RootViewController" customModule="myProject" customModuleProvider="target">
```